# How we can access the ArrayList object of activity class in a static method of another java class in android?

Tags: android

I need to access the ArrayList object of activity class to get the values to show on expandable list view.

```
public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {

    //here i need access the arraylist object

    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<String>  size = new ArrayList<String>();
    size.add("Regular");
    size.add("Large");

    List<String> Addons = new ArrayList<String>();
    Addons.add("one small cheese");
    Addons.add("chicken");

    expandableListDetail.put("Choice of Size", size);
    expandableListDetail.put("Choice of Add ons", Addons);


    return expandableListDetail;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a static ArrayList(eg: itemList) in your activity

```
static ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
```

access the created array list like below,

```
ArrayList<Item> list = YOURACTIVITYNAME.itemList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create two separate functions - one for creating the `size` and the other for creating the `Addons`. And then in your `Activity` just call the functions to set the `expandableListDetail`.

```
expandableListDetail.put("Choice of Size", getSizes());
expandableListDetail.put("Choice of Add ons", getAddons());
```

So basically, you just have to split the `getData` method into two parts and provide the necessary lists to your `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a static function and you need to access normal ArrayList object of activity class in a static method so, the rule of static keyword is that if you have static function then inside the static function all the member must be static.

For your case, you need to make static of your ArrayList object of activity class and then after try.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to make that ArrayList as public and static in your activity like below.

```
public static ArrayList<String> myList;
```

and use this array list in your another class in getData() method like below

```
ActivityName.myList;
```